# How to calculate $\ \sqrt{-i}$ without trigonometric form

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, radicals

I'm trying to calculate $\ \sqrt{-i}$. I've seen other answers using the trigonometric form, but I was trying this way:

$\ \sqrt{-i}$ = $\ \sqrt{-1} * \sqrt{i} $ = $\ ({-1})^{1/2} * ({({-1})^{1/2}})^{1/2} $ = $\ ({-1})^{3/4} $

The result i get from wolfram is $\ -({-1})^{3/4} $.

Comment: For square roots (or fractional exponents in general) of complex numbers, you always have to say which branch you are taking, otherwise you're going to produce nonsense or ambiguities like this. In particular, the equation $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ does not always hold.

Comment: Do you mean the solution for $x$ and $y$ of sth like
$$
(x+iy)^n = a+ib
$$
? then expand it and see how it looks like

Comment: In particular, $\sqrt{-i} =$ **either** $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1-i)$.
$\sqrt{-1} =$ **either** $\pm i.$
$\sqrt{i} =$ **either** $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for the way the surd ($\sqrt{x}$) behaves don't carry over to the complex numbers.  For instance,

$$4 = \sqrt{16} = \sqrt{(-4)(-4)} = \sqrt{-4}\sqrt{-4} = (2i)(2i) =-4$$

doesn't work.  The step at the 3rd equal sign isn't valid in the complex numbers.  And what you've done is essentially the same thing in your first step.

You might do this geometrically.  In the complex plane, $-i$ is at the point $(0,-1)$ which vector is $270$ degrees from the positive $x$-axis.  So one of its square roots has angle $270/2 = 135$ degrees.  I don't know if you count dealing with a 45-45 right triangle as "trigonometry", but it's easy to compute the square root as $(-1+i)/\sqrt{2}$ from here.

Comment: "without trigonometric form" doesn't say without trigonometry. I suspect that using angle to describe a complex number is what they're referring to.

Answer (score 5):

If $(a+bi)^2=-i$ with $a,b\in\mathbb R$, then $a^2-b^2=0$ and $2ab=-1$.

Thus $a=\pm b$, but $a=b$ wouldn't work with $2ab=-1$, so $a=-b$.

That means $-2a^2=-1$, so $a=\pm\dfrac1{\sqrt2}$ and $b=-a$ are solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Half its argument in the complex plane is $\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$

Accordingly in its exponential form

$$ z= e ^{i \dfrac{3\pi}{4}}$$

Comment: "without trigonometric form" I suspect that this answer falls under that category.

Comment: I  gathered  trig should not *explicitly* occur.

Comment: What could "trigonometric form" possibly mean, if it is not a synonym for polar coordinates? At least that's how I read the question.

Comment: It would come in indirectly as in the accepted answer also. Do you suggest I delete my answer?

Comment: Nah. It is just a personal suspicion; I am not an arbiter of truth. And regardless, this answer has value. No reason to remove it.